# Phalcon and Nginx return 403?

Tags: nginx, phalcon

I've set my Nginx config up like below:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    index index.php;
    set $root_path '/var/www/webroot/ROOT/public';
    root $root_path;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And installed Phalcon inside the `ROOT` folder. However, Phalcon keeps displaying the 403 page. I can't find any errors in the logs; the only thing I have is that when I run `service nginx reload` that throws `[emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)`. When I run `sudo service nginx reload` though, it executes without any errors.

Do you guys have any clue what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use your configuration, but it gave me a 503 error.

Please try the configuration below.

```
server {
    listen 81;

    set $root_path \'/var/www/webroot/ROOT/public\';

    root /var/www/webroot/ROOT/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;
    location /{
        root $root_path;
        index index.php;

        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO    $fastcgi_path_info;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If you setup nginx, php-fpm and phalcon properly it should work !